# Spark: How to split an RDD[T]` into Seq[RDD[T]] and preserve the ordering

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

How can I effectively split up an `RDD[T]` into a `Seq[RDD[T]]` / `Iterable[RDD[T]]` with `n` elements and preserve the original ordering?

I would like to be able to write something like this

```
RDD(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).split(3)
```

which should result in something like

```
Seq(RDD(1, 2, 3), RDD(4, 5, 6), RDD(7, 8, 9))
```

Does spark provide such a function? If not what is a performant way to achieve this?

```
val parts = rdd.length / n
val rdds = rdd.zipWithIndex().map{ case (t, i) => (i - (i % parts), t)}.groupByKey().values.map(iter => sc.parallelize(iter.toSeq)).collect
```

Doesn't look very fast..

Comment: This doesn't make any sense - an RDD is a reference to something split around the cluster. You want a bunch of different cluster nodes to each have... a reference to something that's split across all the cluster nodes??
Possibly `rdd.mapPartitions(_.grouped(3))` does what you want, but I'd suggest taking a step back and asking about your problem at a higher level - what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Yes you are right. I need something like Seq[RDD[T]] or Iterable[RDD[T]]. I will edit the question...

Comment: Still not making a lot of sense - it's better to have the RDD at top level so the partitions are as coarse as possible.

Comment: I know what you mean. But the initial RDD comes from a really huge file and for my use case I have to process big batches of this file, one after the other in a loop.. Because it is possible to process each of these big batches in a distributed manner, they have to be of type RDD. 
Does this make sense?

Comment: You want to process all of them, no? So having each cluster node do complete batches is going to be more efficient than distributing each batch individually (I mean, I'm assuming you have more batches than cluster nodes here). (Certainly an RDD of 3 elements is silly - the clustering overhead will be much bigger than the gain - though I trust that's just an example)

Comment: Actually more than that, an RDD of a few million integers is still quite silly - the point of an RDD is for when a dataset is too big to fit into memory on a single node.

Comment: Yes. This was just a symbolic example.. I can't process the batches in parallel because the result of one batch computation will be the argument to the next batch computation.. And this batches are to large to fit in main memory of one node... So an RDD for each batch makes sense to me.

Comment: Maybe you want spark-streaming? That's oriented towards giving you an ordered series of RDDs.

Comment: yes.. I also thought of that.. Do you know how to convert a `RDD` into a `DStream`?

Comment: @RobindeBois you can use queueStream() which allows you to pass a queue of RDDs to create a DStream

Comment: If you need the result of a batch for the next one, looks like what you want is to loop for the nr of batches you need and load a specific set of data every time. Will be more efficient than loading an RDD and filtering data out of it.

Comment: @maasg sounds good.. but how can I "load" just a part (given the offset and the length) of a file in an rdd?

Comment: are you loading a single file from a local FS?

Answer (score 0):

You can, technically, do what you're suggesting. However, it really doesn't make sense in the context of leveraging a computing cluster to perform distributed processing of big data. It goes against the entire point of Spark in the first place. If you do a groupByKey and then try to extract these into separate RDDs, you are effectively pulling all of the data distributed in the RDD onto the driver and then re-distributing each one back to the cluster. If the driver can't load the entire data file, it won't be able to perform this operation either.

You should not be loading large data files onto the driver node from a local file system. You should move your file onto a distributed filesystem like HDFS or S3. Then you can load your single big data file onto your cluster by means of `val lines = SparkContext.textFile(...)` into an RDD of lines. When you do this, each worker in the cluster will only load a portion of the file, which can be done because the data is already distributed across the cluster in the distributed filesystem.

If you then need to organize the data into "batches" that are important to the functional processing of the data, you can key the data with an appropriate batch-identifier, like: `val batches = lines.keyBy( line => lineBatchID(line) )`

Each batch can then be reduced to a batch-level summary, and these summaries can be reduced into a single overall result.

For the purposes of testing Spark code, it is fine to load a *small* sample of a data file onto a single machine. But when it comes to the full dataset, you should be leveraging a distributed filesystem in conjunction with a spark cluster to process this data.